# undo Linux's rm?

Tags: linux, undo, rm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UNDO  LINUX  Trash Command](https://superuser.com/questions/31171/undo-linux-trash-command)

Hi,

Is there any simple way to undo an `rm` command?

The question is purely theoretical; I have NEVER deleted the log of a benchmark queue who took a whole lunchtime to run.

Comment: dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/31171/undo-in-command-line-operation

Comment: ...or at least very closely related, even if the question itself is formulated to be a little more general

Answer (score 41):

On ubuntu or similar:

```
$ sudo apt-get install trash-cli
$ alias rm=trash
```

Then put that alias in .bashrc or the appropriate login script for your shell of choice.

The `trash-cli` package is a command-line interface to the same trash can that GNOME and KDE and other use. So anything you delete via the `trash` command can be restored by GNOME/KDE and vice-versa.

The other commands in the `trash-cli` package are `trash-list`, `trash-empty`, and `restore-trash`.

Comment: +1 for trash-cli, -1 for aliasing rm.

Comment: What's wrong with aliasing `rm`? I like having an undo button for my accidental deletions, even on the command line. Also, `trash-cli` explicitly facilitates this by accepting (and ignoring) many GNU `rm` options.   
Besides, the OP asked for a way to undo rm. This solution doesn't answer the question correctly without the alias.

Comment: @Ryan: Because you get used to rm to meaning something different than what the rm command really does, and then you make a mistake when it isn't aliased.  Get used to using the trash command instead and that can't happen.

Comment: @Roger: Or...you can alias `rm` and then hypnotize yourself into forgetting that you did.  That way you can still keep using `rm` as though it's final.... but if you slip up and go "oh noes!!" you're not completely screwed. (i.e. don't rely on it's "recoverable" functionality)

Comment: @RyanThompson: This is a nice tip, but how to configure this to work also with `sudo rm`?

Comment: Hopefully you'll have an answer to that soon enough: http://superuser.com/questions/192725/how-can-i-alias-a-command-for-sudo

Comment: @Roger you could consider set up an alias to enable undo for 3rd party scripts.

Comment: In support of not aliasing `rm`: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/17637/37190

Comment: Just for completeness, it is possible to recover, if you've just deleted the file and it wasn't already overwritten in disk. I've done it before a while back using low level tool(s), but honestly I forgot. There's probably an answer with the details somewhere in stack exchange. But for the future, using `trash` is the way. I use an alias reminder instead, e.g.: `alias rm='echo "tip: use trash next time"; rm'`, that way I retain functionality and the choice.

Answer (score 16):

The traditional answer is:

> You recover the file from the latest backup. You do have a recent backup, don't you?

because on many unix filesystems this simple isn't possible, or is very difficult.

As others have noted this is not the end-all and be-all of the issue any more, but not making mistakes of this kind is still the preferred approach.

Comment: I really intend to put all my scripts on a hourly-committed bzr repository.

Comment: The modern answer is: Recover the file from a recent filesystem snapshot. :-)

Comment: Thats a cool question... I usually don't make backups of ~/Downloads... and wiped out my content by passing `rm -fr *(1)*` ... every file wen away. So having backups is not always the solution. Trash-cli sounds cools.

Comment: No, having backups is _ALWAYS_ the solution. Just because you chose not to backup something, doesn't make backing up not the solution, it makes you silly, for not backing up something.

Comment: "You do have a recent backup, don't you?" "[...], but not making mistakes of this kind is still the preferred approach." - Wow, great level of arrogance which is absolutely no help to the question at hand.

Answer (score 4):

To prevent hypopthetical future mistakes, you might want to `alias rm='rm -i'`...

Comment: I generally think that this would never prevent any errors (the 'y' is typed quite automatically), but consume a lot of time, and encourage the use of He-Whose-Name-Must-Not-Be-Mentioned rm -rf.

Comment: It does give you one extra go though before messing things up. I generally just `ls` with the same parameters before so I can see what's going to go.

Comment: I usually delete files on purpose, I just realize I needed those files later. So interactive wouldn't help