# Change terminal colors when connecting to remote server, Linux

Tags: linux, terminal, konsole, remote-connection

I have a habit of changing the terminal background to another color scheme when connected to a remote server. This prevents lots of [theoretical, unfortunate mishaps](https://superuser.com/questions/32355/undo-linuxs-rm).

Is there a way to change the desktop background automatically, preferably to a color different color scheme for each server? I use konsole, but willing to change a terminal emulator for this feature.

Thanks,

Udi

Comment: I'm a bit confused - do you want to change the terminal background or the desktop background?

Comment: I upvoted this because it's a great technique and something I already do... in fact I use unique colors using the prompt command for each server... the prompts are the same, but the colors i type in and the base color is different for each of my servers. it's the easiest way of looking at a terminal withouth having to read anything (even a title bar or prompt) and KNOW FOR SURE, which server you're connected to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hm, changing background colors could get messy, but changing the [color of the prompt](http://hardlosers.r09.railsrumble.com/permalink/16) when you login to your remove server should be easy. Just add it to [your `.bashrc` file](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/howtos/Bash-Prompt/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO-2.html).

Comment: I like that idea: you could have a bright red background like this one: http://hardlosers.r09.railsrumble.com/permalink/44

Answer (score 0):

You could make a different terminal profile for each server, and use a different color scheme for each. This would require you to start a new terminal for each new connection, instead of just using ssh in an existing one.