# How can I alias a command for sudo?

Tags: linux, shell, sudo

I have an alias that I would like to use both as a regular user and as root, via sudo. Specifically, it is this:

```
alias rm=trash
```

This works fine as a normal user, and it works fine when I use `sudo -i` to get a root shell prompt, but if I use `sudo rm`, the alias does not apply. So where do I need to put my alias so that it works in one-off sudo commands?

Comment: You don't specify if you are on OS X, but if so, check out the osx-trash command. Very useful: http://www.dribin.org/dave/osx-trash/ But as others have said, don't alias rm. Just get in the habit of typing "trash" instead.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/61321/how-to-pass-alias-through-sudo

Answer (score 11):

Create an alias for sudo with a space at the end:

```
alias sudo='sudo '
```

Then all other aliases will work with sudo.

But like mentioned in the other answer, aliasing `rm` to execute `trash` is probably a bad idea.
What I like to do is "disable" `rm` like this:

```
alias rm='echo "rm is disabled, use trash or /bin/rm instead."'
```

With this you will soon get into the habit of typing `trash` instead of `rm`.

Comment: Nice idea with the alias! I don't like disabling it though. One variation is to keep it and still use the reminder, e.g.: `alias rm='echo "tip: use trash next time"; rm'`.

Answer (score 1):

That won't work, but if you use a function and export it, it will.

```
dl () { trash "$@"; }
export -f dl
```

It's a bad idea to alias `rm` because if you get in the habit of the alias or function protecting you and at some point the alias isn't available for some reason then you use `rm` and it deletes a bunch of stuff that will be difficult to get back.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work with either bash or zsh.