# How can I pass an alias to sudo?

Tags: bash, sudo, alias

I have tried putting my aliases in `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/profile`, and `/etc/bashrc`.

I am still unable to execute the following:

```
alias zf2="php public/index.php"
```

and then execute:

```
sudo zf2 orm:info
```

The issue seems to be that I am unable to specify an alias as a command using visudo-- which causes a syntax error.

So I am unable to call:

```
sudo zf2 orm:info
```

However, I was able to create a script at /usr/share/scripts/zf2 which contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

alias zf2="php public/index.php"
zf2 $1
```

and add this script as the command in visudo. When this script is in the end user's PATH I am able to execute

```
zf2 orm:info
```

I have different aliases like `zf2` that I need to expose to the end user. I would prefer to maintain alias instead of a collection of scripts.

Comment: Unfortunately I want to use aliases in visudo and I am unable.

Comment: That is not possible.  Aliases are handled by the shell (in your case bash) and expanded before being sent to the application.   `sudo` itself knows nothing about aliases.

Comment: Because @Steven is technically correct, you should clarify whether you simply want to expand aliases _prior_ to `sudo` being passed the line, or whether you want the aliases expanded in the elevated environment.  Pedantry isn't merely a way to elicit eye-rolls.  (Wow, but that last sentence doesn't look kosher at all.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I alias a command for sudo?](https://superuser.com/questions/192725/how-can-i-alias-a-command-for-sudo)

Comment: Try it with `sudo -E`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Ironically, the solution is to call `sudo` from an alias.

```
alias sd="sudo "
```

Note: While not recommended, you could name the alias `sudo`: `alias sudo="sudo "`

> [Bash Reference Manual (Aliases)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases)
>
> If the last character of the alias value is a blank, then the next
>   command word following the alias is also checked for alias expansion.

Comment: I can maybe see reasons why someone would and would not want this done as the default for any system.  The convenience and expectation as asked, versus being more careful with elevated privileges.

Comment: `alias sd="sudo "` maychance?

Comment: After reviewing my aliases I noticed that I did not have `alias sudo="sudo "` in the end users environment. This is the answer