# linux terminal undo rm 'somefile'

Tags: linux, terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [undo Linux's rm?](https://superuser.com/questions/32355/undo-linuxs-rm)

is it possible to undo a `rm somefile` command in linux?

and if so, how does one do that?

Comment: The classic beginner's trap.

Comment: What is you OS? FS?

Answer (score 43):

`rm` doesn't move the file to some *trash* directory, it deletes it. Thus you cannot, in *normal* ways.

You could try with some tool to find removed files on the filesystem. If you want to try I suggest you to immediately unmount your filesystem and not mount it (in readwrite) until you found back your files or until you give up.

If you're scared of removing files, you should replace your `rm` command with another one that asks confirmation before permanently remove files. You can use an alias to this purpose:

```
alias rm="rm -i"
```

Comment: Or replace it with a command that moves them to a .trash folder instead of deleting them.

Comment: The hint is good, but this not really answers how "to undo a rm somefile". More info about "some tool to find removed files on the filesystem" would improve this answer alot. Just some honorable mentions: [foremost](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-recover-deleted-files-using-foremost-in-linux/) and [testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)

Answer (score 20):

Not normally, no - it's been deleted, and there isn't normally an undelete comand. It's for that reason that the very first thing that my first Software Engineering professor told the class to do was to redefine the rm command to mv (move) the file(s) to a .trash folder.

Comment: For this, you could also use something like [trash-cli](https://www.tecmint.com/trash-cli-manage-linux-trash-from-command-line/).

Answer (score 8):

[Here is a good article *(Archive)*](http://web.archive.org/web/20080330034647/http://www.xs4all.nl/%7Ecarlo17/howto/undelete_ext3.html). The original [link](http://www.xs4all.nl/%7Ecarlo17/howto/undelete_ext3.html) is deprecated.

Quoting:

> The most frequently quoted passage
> comes from the ext3 FAQ itself:
>
> Q: How can I recover (undelete)
> deleted files from my ext3 partition?
>
> Actually, you can't! This is what one
> of the developers, Andreas Dilger,
> said about it:
>
> In order to ensure that ext3 can
> safely resume an unlink after a crash,
> it actually zeros out the block
> pointers in the inode, whereas ext2
> just marks these blocks as unused in
> the block bitmaps and marks the inode
> as "deleted" and leaves the block
> pointers alone.
>
> Your only hope is to "grep" for parts
> of your files that have been deleted
> and hope for the best.

Comment: That would be interesting to grep the filesystem device for parts of the file.  Might actually work, at least in part.

Comment: @David, the article linked is about ext3grep