# Prevent user typing accidental space between rm and wildcard

Tags: linux, bash, rm

Intention:

```
rm -rf string*
```

Problem:

```
rm -rf string *
```

The first case is a legitimate and common use of rm, a small typo can cause a lot of problems in the second case. Is there a simple way to smartly protect against an accidental trailing or leading wildcard?

Comment: With a recent and well configured shell (`zsh` or `bash`) I would rather take the habit of pressing the tab key (to trigger auto-completion) before pressing the return key

Comment: `touch -- -i` will create a file `-i` that will be passed to `rm` as the parameter `-i` when you include a wildcard in your arguments.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: If you happen to be in the directory where the file exists.

Comment: @MartinSchröder That will only work if you type `rm *`. If you typ `rm name *`, it will expand to `rm name -i other names`. `-i` won't be processed as an option because it's not before the filenames.

Comment: @Barmar: Try that. It works with the GNU utils.

Comment: @MartinSchröder So it does!

Comment: Typically, a user only does this once.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A `DEBUG` trap could be written to cancel commands that look suspicious. The following, or code similar to it, can be added to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
shopt -s extdebug
checkcommand() {
  if [[ $BASH_COMMAND = 'rm -r'*' *' ]]; then
    echo "Suppressing rm -r command ending in a wildcard" >&2
    return 1
  fi
  # check for other commands here, if you like
  return 0
}
trap checkcommand DEBUG
```

Adjust the logic to taste.

(I don't actually expect this approach to be useful -- too many ways to mess up a command destructively to find them testing one-by-one -- but it provides a literal answer to the question).

Answer (score 46):

There is no way to a totally bulletproof a system.  And adding "Are you sure?" prompts to things is both counterproductive and leads to "Of course I'm sure." kneejerk reactions.

A trick I picked up from a book in years past is to first do `ls -R blah*` then, do  `rm -fr blah*`  if and only if the listing that ls turned up hit what I wanted hit.

It's easy enough to do the `ls` command first, then <kbd>↑</kbd>, delete the `ls -R` and replace with `rm -fr`.

The final question is, "If the information was valuable to you, where's your backup?"

Comment: Rather than up arrow you can use `^ls -R^rm -rf^` and maybe set as an alias

Comment: This also has the advantage that it won't do harm if you bump the enter key, or bump your mouse and paste in something with newlines.  I sometimes enter things in a less efficient order just for more safety, e.g. `cat > .log`, then go back in and paste or yank the filename before the `.log`.  So at no point do I have `> valuablefile` on the cmdline.

Comment: I use rm aliased to `rm -i`, so I often just compose my rm command and then put a `\ ` at the beginning of the line.  (`\rm` avoids alias-expansion for rm, since part of the word was quoted).  If I needed a `-r` or `-f`, yeah I sometimes start with `ls` instead of `rm`, or just leave off the `-rf` part.  (edit, how do you get a backslash code-formatting?  bquote bslash bslash bquote fails.

Answer (score 8):

Can you train yourself to use, say, `rmrf` in place of `rm -rf`?

If so, this bash function will provide you a chance to see what would actually happen before confirming the command:

```
rmrf() { echo rm -rf "$@"; read -p "Proceed (y/N)? "; [ "${REPLY,,}" = y ] && rm -rf "$@"; }
```

To make this function permanent, add this line to the `~/.bashrc` file on each computer you use.

#### Comparison with the common `rm` alias

It is common to define an alias:

```
alias rm='rm -i'
```

This has two limitations:

1. If you come to depend on this alias, then you will in for a shock when you are on a machine or in an environment that does not have it.  By contrast, trying to run `rmrf` on a machine without that function will return a harmless `command not found`.
2. This alias is no help in your case because the `-f` option that you supply on the command line overrides the `-i` option in the alias.

Comment: @JakeGould And *don't use rm -f unless you really need to*.

Comment: Why bother with `rmrf`, as opposed to just creating a shell function `rm` that checks for the arguments `-r` or `-rf`, and enacts special logic in that case, otherwise directly calling `command rm "$@"` to invoke the real `rm` command?

Comment: You use a different name so you don't shoot yourself in the foot when your override isn't there.  And I agree with @MichaelKjörling, you don't need `-f` if you don't have `-i`.  Leaving off `-f` gives you extra warning before removing a readonly file, for example.

Answer (score 6):

If I am in a situation where deleting the wrong files is a really big deal, one of the things I've done is make a trashcan folder, like `mkdir trashcan`, and then I have a script `rmTrashcan` which has a `rm -rf trashcan/*` or `rm -rf *` or similar, written very carefully and checked several times.

That way, if I make a mistake, the mistake is on a `mv` command, not a `rm` command.  Once I do a `ls` and am confident of *exactly* what I am deleting, a `rmTrashcan` actually does the dirty work safely.

It was also tremendously convenient for a situation where I had to delete backups.  I could `mv` an entire month of backups into the trashcan, `mv` the few I wanted to keep (1st of month, 15th of month) back into the backups, then `rmTranshcan` the rest.  Doing a similar command is hard to do with `rm` on its own, and doing it this way let me `ls` the backups to be confident in what files I am leaving behind (rather than just enumerating the files I intend to delete)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of bothering with two commands (`ls` and `rm`), I think a simpler and easier way is to use `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "string*" -delete
```

If you accidentally type `"string *"` it will delete files named `string chars` and `string letters` (which is what you wanted anyway), but it won't grab every file like `*` in a shell will.

Also, you can leave off the `-delete` to see which files it's going to delete, then hit up arrow and type `-delete` easier than typing `^ls -R^rm -rf` or other nonsense.

Comment: A `find` will do a nested search for files that match instead of the just the explicit parameters declared on the commandline.  I think this misses the mark.  I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a simple way to smartly protect against an accidental
>   trailing or leading wildcard?

Not really. It’s proposed in another answer you could create a custom command to add a prompt before executing a task. But the problem with this custom command is it must be consciously installed on systems you are working on. And even if it is installed, the problem is your reflex to hit `y` to get the task done with could come into play.

Meaning this is all a user interface issue even if it is on a text/command line level. How many safety nets do you expect there to be to protect you from doing something you shouldn’t? It’s like a pair of scissors: If you are somehow negligent and slip and cut your hand while intending to cut cloth or paper, who is at fault? Or even traffic lights and stop signs: There’s really nothing stopping a driver from running a light or ignoring traffic signs other than an acute awareness of what might happen if they do engage in such risky behavior.

That said the best, realistic solution lies in system permissions for users as well as groups. That is the best/only real safety net to protect a user from themselves.

If you are working on a system where you are the only one accessing it, you might be tempted to just `chmod 777` everything, but that is not the way a rational system is setup. Instead permissions should be something like `755` for all directories and `644` for all non-executable files. Executable files should be `755` at the least, but maybe even `744` if you only want others to read but not run the files.

Answer (score 2):

Try composing your initial `rm` command without the `-f` flag, but with `-i` instead, such that `rm` will prompt you for each file it intends to delete.
For small recursive deletions, you can hold down the <kbd>y</kbd> key, once you're sure the command has been typed correctly.  For large deletions, you can abort the operation, and use commandline history to carefully change the `-i` to a `-f`.

Comment: You actually have to press `y[RETURN]` every file, there's nothing you can hold down with GNU rm.  Editting out the `-i` is the way to go, once you have the command typed properly.  Then you get a prompt only on a read-only file, and maybe other things.

Comment: Just use `rm -I` so that it only prompts once, and only for potentially dangerous deletions (i.e. of many files.)

Comment: In less constructive forums, my answer would have been something along the lines of "If your typing/proofreading is that bad, you've no business using 'rm -rf' with wildcards."

I didn't know of the -I switch...  must've been put in <20 years ago; 'bout the last time I did 'man rm'.  :)

Answer (score 2):

rm has `-i` and `-I` flags to confirm before every removal.  In the past, some distributions have turned them on by default.  This is a terrible idea.  Give the user too many confirmation dialogs for normal operations and they'll begin to habitually confirm them.  This just shifts the requirement to "be careful" (always a red flag) to a new and more annoying dialog.  "Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes! YES! God damnit, stupid computer just delete the files YESYESYESYESYES--CRAP I MEANT NO! NOOOOOOO!"  This is the "Yes, but I meant no" dialog problem.  [This answer provides a visual explanation](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/71974/28069) of why confirmation dialogs come at the wrong time.

The sort of mistake you describe is a [slip](http://www.efcog.org/wg/ism_pmi_hpi/docs/HPI_Articles_Of_Interest/Norman,%20Donald%20A%20-%20Categorization%20of%20action%20slips%20%281981%29.pdf), "the performance of an action which was not what was intended".  The user typically immediately recognizes the mistake and knows exactly how to fix it.  Unfortunately, Unix does not give the user the opportunity, rm deletes the file immediately.  Every other operating system solves this problem by allowing deletions to be undone, at least for a little while, by the use of the Trash.

There are various trash systems for Unix, and [this answer is full of suggestions](https://superuser.com/questions/31171/undo-the-linux-trash-command).

The question is to alias rm or not to alias rm.  Pros to aliasing rm...

1. You can't make the slip of forgetting to use the rm alternative.

Cons to aliasing rm...

1. You might come to rely on it on systems which don't have it.
2. Might cause problems when the disk is nearly full.
3. Need infrastructure to periodically empty the trash.
4. Have to be sure not to interfere with the expected behavior of rm in programs.
5. Might not fully emulate rm.

If you follow the first argument too far, you wind up using vi (not vim, vi), csh (not tcsh, csh) and other antiquated utilities because they're universally available. Still, there is a danger of overcustomizing your environment. I prefer to take my utilities with me and to make that as easy as possible. YMMV.

Two and three are technical problems.  They can be solved with a clever reaper job which checks the size of the trash and periodically cleans things up, similar to a [tmpreaper](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/tmpreaper.8.html).  This can be a cron job, or a more clever version can make use of the various file system event infrastructures available on many desktop Linux distributions.  This is not simple, and even harder to do efficiently. Its better to find an existing system than to try to make your own.

The fourth can be dealt with by making your new rm a shell alias, `alias rm='trash'`, then it will not affect programs.

The fifth is a problem I leave for the reader to solve. rm doesn't have a lot of switches.

Comment: I have rm aliased to `rm -i`, but I often use `\rm` to get the unaliased behaviour.  I type `rm -i` any time I'm PLANNING to say no to one of the args.  I sometimes start the command with `ls` as the command, then only put in the \rm when I'm done.  So there's no way I can accidentally hit return on `rm -rf /` instead of `/.../file`

Comment: `rm -I` or `rm --interactive=once` is far, far less annoying than `rm -i`, and still catches aything dangerous (it only prompts when there are more than 3 files, or if it's recursive, and just ONCE instead of FOR EACH FILE.)

Comment: @Kundor Yes, and it doesn't change the equation. It probably makes it more likely the user will ignore it. The user has a goal: delete stuff. The prompt says "are you sure you want to delete the stuff you just told me to delete?" The user is still fixated on the goal of deleting stuff, not verifying what is to be deleted, so they say "yes" without thinking. `-i` might give the user time to change goals. [This answer on a related question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/71974/28069) lays it all out.

Comment: @Schwern: but no one can possibly live with `rm -i` for more than 30 seconds without turning it off. Whereas `rm -I` only prompts when it's likely that you've screwed up; the prompt only comes up for big deletions. When you were trying to delete a couple of things and the prompt is given, you are taken aback and realize that you accidentally typed "foo *".

Comment: @Kundor Deleting more than three files and deleting recursively (the confirmation is disabled by the habitual `-rf` I just discovered) are poor proxies for detecting a likely screw up. Wanting to delete a sub-directory isn't a likely screw up. The message doesn't help because it just confirms what the user said to do without adding useful information at a point when the user is not looking to verify. "rm: remove 1 argument recursively?" "Yes, delete the directory, I just told you to do that! ... wait, which directory was that?  CRAP!!!"

Comment: It comes down to this: rm can't know if the files its deleting were meant to be deleted. Only the user knows this. Sure, there are some system files and big operations (like deleting /), those are easy. rm can't tell that `rm -I stuff.txt` just deleted an important phone number, but `rm -Ir stuff/ things/` is all temporary junk and cat pictures. Any proxy is going to contain far more false alarms than real ones. Confirmation dialogs come *too soon*, are *too easy to dismiss*, and are *usually wrong* to change the user's thinking from "delete stuff" to "is this stuff important".

Answer (score 2):

I teach everyone about the `!$` = last argument in the last command trick:

```
% ls job[XYZ].*
jobX.out1
jobX.out2
[rest of the matches]

% rm !$
```

This allows an inspection of the wildcard expansion, and then use of the exact same glob pattern without the possibility of inserting a space before the `*`.

Also I suggest people never cut and paste a globbing wildcard pattern on a potentially destructive command line.  Because in my own hands that has been a problem :)

A tech in my lab just made this mistake last week (3 months of work) - and yes we had a backup (1-day behind).

Answer (score 0):

Everyone seems to be saying, "Be more careful", "Don't make an alias/confirmation prompt because you'll become habituated to not paying proper attention to it".

Cool, and everything.  I mean, I don't think you should make an alias for `rm` (nor `rmrf`, since you could easily screw that up and type the real command).

But why can't you make an alias/script and call it, say, `remove` and only feed it one argument (eg $1)?  The wildcard should be $2, because of the inadvertent space (amiright?) and thus your script/wrapper/alias won't be fed the second one.  Yes, you can only do one set of deletions (with a wildcard) at a time, but that's the price you'd pay.

If I were writing something nice, I might have it tell me the number of files and directories it's planning on deleting, and the total size of stuff I was deleting, and then ask for a confirm, but that might impede your flow.  Maybe make that a flag option on `remove`? (-i).   You might also wish to do a check $1 to see if it's *just* a single wildcard and ask for a confirmation, and list which directory you're actually in.

---

As an aside, there are a number of `rm` replacements out there.  Many are trying to be compliant with the UI desktop trash.  Some of those might be worth looking into.

Comment: Your "remove" alias will never remove more than one file at a time.  You cannot use a wildcard, because the shell expands it before the command sees it.

Comment: So do an eval on it, and then pull that into the script?

Comment: So you want to type `remove \*`?  If your script lets the shell glob-expand its input, I don't see it helping much.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple trick is to put `-rf` at the end: `rm whatever* -rf`
This reduce drasticaly the error rate, because you type more character after the `*`, so you have more time to see typos.
This does not solve everything. Just a simple everyday trick.